# How do i create an image site map for drupal 7 site?

Tags: drupal-7, sitemap

I am maintaining a drupal 7 site with more than 500 pages. Most of the pages contains images.
I want to create image site map for my site.

Example [image site map reference from google](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178636)

ie, i want to list out images under each url. I have tried curl to retrieve images form each url. But it takes more time to execute each url.

Is there any easy and fastest way to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a contributed module Google Image Sitemap

[Google Image Sitemap](https://drupal.org/project/google_image_sitemap)

I'll do some tests and in a few days I hope you can tell something more